# Where am I going wrong in formatting?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to break my head with the formatting... could someone point me as to where am I going wrong?

```
declare @jsql varchar(200)
declare @casenbr varchar(12)
declare @TransactionNbr int

set @casenbr = '200812345'
set @TransactionNbr = 7455678
SET @JimsSql =  'EXEC JIMSdb.dbo.spItsLoadCaseDocumentsFromJIMS_TransNbr ''''' + @CaseNbr + ''''', + ' + @TransactionNbr 

print @jsql
```

I get the error

> error converting varchar to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The varchar is ...

```
'EXEC JIMSdb.dbo.spItsLoadCaseDocumentsFromJIMS_TransNbr ''''' + @CaseNbr + ''''', + '
```

... and the int is...

```
@TransactionNbr
```

You need to cast `@TransactionNbr` as a varchar, too:

```
SET @JimsSql =  'EXEC JIMSdb.dbo.spItsLoadCaseDocumentsFromJIMS_TransNbr ''''' + @CaseNbr + ''''', + ' + cast(@TransactionNbr as varchar(56))
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL is not forgiving when combining strings and numbers, so you need to convert your integer to a string first, possibly just casting it to `varchar`:

```
SET @JimsSql =  '...blah...' + cast(@TransactionNbr as varchar(10))
```

Your quotes are all over the place too - inside a string, two single-quotes get escaped to one, so you need to watch where you're at. I believe what you're looking for is:

```
SET @JimsSql =  'EXEC JIMSdb.dbo.spItsLoadCaseDocumentsFromJIMS_TransNbr ''' + @CaseNbr + ''', ' + cast(@TransactionNbr  as varchar(10))
```

This will print out:

```
EXEC JIMSdb.dbo.spItsLoadCaseDocumentsFromJIMS_TransNbr '200812345', 7455678
```

That said, if you're planning on executing this statement instead of just printing it, then you're opening yourself up for SQL injection, just as if you weren't parameterizing this in the first place. You may want to look into [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @jsql nvarchar(MAX)
declare @casenbr varchar(12)
declare @TransactionNbr int

set @casenbr = '200812345'
set @TransactionNbr = 7455678
SET @jsql =  'EXEC JIMSdb.dbo.spItsLoadCaseDocumentsFromJIMS_TransNbr ''' + @CaseNbr + ''',  ' + CAST(@TransactionNbr AS NVARCHAR) + ''

print @jsql
```

**Result**

```
EXEC JIMSdb.dbo.spItsLoadCaseDocumentsFromJIMS_TransNbr '200812345',  7455678
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the following in your @jsql query just to make sure it is accepted as var by SQL

```
 cast(@TransactionNbr as varchar)
```